# Bootstrap 3 Navbar not transitioning properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions

I've been playing around with bootstrap 3 and am trying to create a navbar that transitions in from the top after scrolling past the initial header section of my html. I'm almost there.  I have used 'affix' to successfully add the navbar after the scroll and have also had some success with the transition. However I'm still having 2 (I hope minor) problems.

1) the transition starts too early. (ie. I don't get all the way past my header before the navbar comes in)

2) the transition doesn't transition out properly, it just snaps out rather then animating out.

**Here is the code I've written:** http://bootply.com/104811

Could anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if you saw my updated answer... I added #2 in there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://bootply.com/104823)

1) Use an element below your header to apply the offset to the affix, like your container. or just hard-code the number of pixels `offset: { top: 100 }`.

```
$('#nav').affix({
    offset: { top: $('#some-lower-element').offset().top }
});
```

2) I think I figured this one out...

If you keep the nav visible (Remove `visibility: hidden`), with `position: fixed` and `top: -50` (just above the top of the screen) the `transition` still works when scrolling up.

```
#nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top:-50px;
    transition: top 1s;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s; /* Safari */
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This took care of both my issues.  The one change I made to your code was I put the new element (#start-offset) a little higher in the document.  I put it within the #nav-wrapper but bellow the #nav.  This way the navbar comes in as soon as the 'pink' header section goes off-screen.

Thanks again for your help!